# halaxa/json-machine is deprecated! What can we use now?

Tags: php, laravel, package, vendor

"message": "Class 'JsonMachine\JsonMachine' not found",
"exception": "Error",

- Root composer.json requires halaxa/json-machine ^0.8.0@dev, dev-master, found halaxa/json-machine[dev-syntax-check, dev-ext, dev-master, dev-issue-62, dev-0_4, dev-push-parsing, v0.1.0, ..., 0.8.0] but it does not match the constraint.

Comment: Nothing on https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine indicates that this package is deprecated. It has received a lot of commits in the last weeks, and even some releases

Answer (score 2):

[CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) keeps track of all the important changes such as the one you've described along with the hint to what to use instead. Also, if you skip no minor version when upgrading, you will be notified of any deprecations beforehand.

JSON Machine is not deprecated and there are no plans to do so.

Edit:
Also, no version matching `0.8.0@dev` was ever released. The closest would be `0.8.0-BETA2` which would be matched by constraint `0.8.0@beta`. That's why Composer complains about it.